# What are the available global GNSS corrections?

Tags: gps, atmospheric-correction

How can I find out what GNSS corrections are available in a location?

For example, in the United Arab Emirates (24°03'22.8"N 55°46'42.9"E) what corrections are available to me assuming I have the best GNSS receiver? Or in this location am I only going to have autonomous GNSS?

Comment: Are you looking for free solutions only? (I don't have an answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no real "global" system but their are different networks.

From the government augmentation system, there is WAAS in North America, EGNOS in Europe, SDCM in Russia, BDSBAS in China, GAGAN in India and MSAS in Japan. More information on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNSS_augmentation) about GNSS augmentation.

In addition, there are commercial systems providing L1 and L1/L2 correction in most parts of the world: OMNISTAR and SARTfix (Fugro).

Then, you could find local beacon station. For instance, there are two beacon station in the Emirates registered with [Trimble](https://www.trimble.com/findbeacon.asp?Nav=File-220903) (The one from Abu Dhaby is close enough to your location).

Finally, you can "do it yourself" if you have the possibility to use a second GNSS receiver as a base station.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the commercial OMNISTAR and SARTfix sources listed by radouxju, Trimble sells RTX (available over Internet as well as via L-Band satellite) which primarily works with Trimble and SpectraPrecision receivers but I think also works with some GNSS receivers sold by other companies.